# How to correctly add time values for elapsed time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I do work for my client on a per-hour basis in that I charge him a set amount for every hour I spend doing his requested work.

I use [toggl.com](http://www.toggl.com) for time tracking

Today, in 3 sessions, I worked for the following amount of time:

Session 1 was 54m 58s long

Session 2 was 19m 06s long

Session 3 was 1h 07m 59s long

How do I add these values together for a sum total of time spent doing work for this client which can then be compared against the hours he has available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enter your times into excel, then use sum:

[image]

Comment: ah, I was only entering `54:58` and `19:06` without the `00:` for hour